# Is it possible to set Environment variables in Makefile - to be used after

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to set an Environment variable in a Makefile, so it can be used  in another program running in the sam shell as `make`, but after `make` has run.

Update: This is not possible according to accepted answer with comments.

Steps:

1. run `make test` setting env: `export TEST_ENV_ONE=OneString`
2. run another program, that can read `TEST_ENV_ONE`

Tried this:

Not working:

```
test:
    export TEST_ENV_ONE=OneString
    $(shell export TEST_ENV_TWO=TwoString)
```

Afterwards this is empty:

```
echo $TEST_ENV_ONE
echo $TEST_ENV_TWO
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want the environment variables to be exported to the shell from which you invoked make things are a bit difficult because, as explained by ネロク, you cannot directly export environment variables from a child process (`make`) to its parent process (the shell from which you invoke `make`). But if you accept to invoke make like this:

```
eval "$(make -s)"
```

then it is indeed possible: just echo `export VARIABLE1=VALUE1; export VARIABLE2=VALUE2; ...` in your recipe. Warning: you will also have to guarantee that nothing else gets echoed by make on the standard input. But you can use the standard error, instead. Example:

```
$ cat Makefile
export TEST_ENV_ONE := OneString

all:
    printf 'make variable TEST_ENV_ONE = %s\n' "$(TEST_ENV_ONE)" 1>&2
    printf 'in-recipe shell variable TEST_ENV_ONE = %s\n' "$$TEST_ENV_ONE" 1>&2
    printf 'export TEST_ENV_ONE="%s"\n' '$(TEST_ENV_ONE)'

$ unset TEST_ENV_ONE
$ printenv TEST_ENV_ONE
$ eval "$(make -s)"
make variable TEST_ENV_ONE = OneString
in-recipe shell variable TEST_ENV_ONE = OneString
$ printenv TEST_ENV_ONE
OneString
```

Note that make more or less considers environment variables as make variables. From GNU make manual:

> Variables in make can come from the environment in which make is run.
> Every environment variable that make sees when it starts up is
> transformed into a make variable with the same name and value.
> However, an explicit assignment in the makefile, or with a command
> argument, overrides the environment. (If the ‘-e’ flag is specified,
> then values from the environment override assignments in the makefile.
> See Summary of Options. But this is not recommended practice.)

So, unless the value of your variable is the result of complex computations by make itself, a much more natural way to obtain the same result would be to define the environment variable in the parent shell and to use it as is in the Makefile:

```
$ cat Makefile
all:
    printf 'make variable TEST_ENV_ONE = %s\n' "$(TEST_ENV_ONE)"
    printf 'in-recipe shell variable TEST_ENV_ONE = %s\n' "$$TEST_ENV_ONE"

$ export TEST_ENV_ONE=OneString
$ make -s
make variable TEST_ENV_ONE = OneString
in-recipe shell variable TEST_ENV_ONE = OneString
$ printenv TEST_ENV_ONE
OneString
```

Comment: `eval "$(make)"`, with the quotes, would have fewer things to go wrong. `eval` is not special syntax -- its arguments are subject to word-splitting and globbing just like anything else.

Answer (score 23):

Your `export TEST_ENV_ONE=OneString` above is running in a dedicated shell. The subsequent commands run in other shell instances. Therefore, they don't inherit the environment variable `TEST_ENV_ONE`.

---

You could use a top-level (i.e., not in a target's recipe) [`export` directive](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables_002fRecursion.html) in the makefile:

```
export env_var := MyEnvVariable

.PHONY: all
all:
    echo env_var: $$env_var
```

This way, the variable `env_var` is exported to the shells that will execute the recipes.

If you run `make` with the makefile above:

```
$ make
echo env_var: $env_var
env_var: MyEnvVariable
```

As you can see from the output, the shell that run `echo env_var: $env_var` had the variable `env_var` in its environment.

Comment: Thanks you are right, and as you write "...had the variable.." My problem is that I need env_var to available in another program - still in the same shell/terminal/bash as make.

Comment: Do you mean it has to be available in the shell that executed `make`?

Comment: Yes, if it is possible

Comment: `make` runs in a child process of that shell, so creating an environment variable in this child process cannot affect the environment of the parent process.

Comment: I would suggest you to create a fresh new question explaining your problem at a higher-level. This seems to me like an XY problem.

Comment: @ChrisG. There are ways to do what you want. Have a look at my answer.